Improve Size in Exasol Docker Image
My Goal: I need to improve the Volume Size of Exasol from 4GiB to 10GiB
What I use:
Exasols official Github Repo/ Docker Image:
https://github.com/exasol/docker-db/
https://hub.docker.com/layers/exasol/docker-db/latest-7.1/images/sha256-3c75362b872385e0dad5b662b6e39a7048877312cd8d728f540855c8a5dfa9a1?context=explore
Together with Docker in WSL.
What I tried
2.1 Running the Container and mounting it:
docker run --name exasoldb -p 127.0.0.1:9091:8563 --detach --privileged --stop-timeout 120 -v ./:/exa  exasol/docker-db:latest-7.1

2.2 Inside the container I improved the Disk size which the Volume uses (standart config)
truncate --size=+10GB /exa/data/storage/dev.1
cshdd --enlarge --node-id 11 -h /exa/data/storage/dev.1

2.3 Shut down the DB, storage service
dwad_client stop-wait DB1
csctrl -d

2.4 Modify the Volume Size of the used Volume:
exaconf modify-volume --name DataVolume1 --size 5GiB --nodes 1 --disk disk1 --num-master-nodes 1

2.5 Commit the changes
exaconf commit

2.6 Restart the container
I also tried:

Mounting the EXAConf and setting
Volume size (e. g. '1 TiB') Size = 10 GiB

Starting the container and in the EXAConf setting the size, setting checksum to commit like:
Checksum = COMMIT
exaconf commit

adding a second DataVolume like
exaconf add-volume --name DataVolume2 --type data --size 10GiB --disk disk1 --redundancy 1 --nodes 1 --owner 500:500
the second volume wont even be listed in the output.


Results:

Changing disk size works. Using
SELECT * FROM EXA_VOLUME_USAGE; in the DB outputs the improved free HDD Size
However the VOLUME_SIZE will stay 4 what-the-heck-ever I did or do.
Output also states the size after all of around 4GB
[root@n11 /]# dwad_client volume-space-info DB1 PERSISTENT VOLUME 0:    NODE: n11       SIZE: 4294967296        USED: 8257536 TEMPORARY VOLUME 1:     NODE: n11       SIZE: 1073741824        USED: 0

Any help is welcomed. The ressources online are very limited online for the issue.
